# How many hashes does an AMD Threadripper 1950X do on the RandomX Monero mining algorithm?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, gpu-mining, random-x

I have an AMD Threadripper 1950X, has there been benchmarks done for mining on RandomX compared to other CPUs and high end GPUs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get about 8k on a TR 1950X.
Some more benchmarks here: https://randomx.jir.dk/

Comment: how much memory do you need? and can you share your xmrig .json profile?

Comment: I am using the default config file from xmrig. Using 4 sticks of RAM 3600 Mhz, with 18-18-18-38 timing. With latest xmrig and 1gb pages feature I currently do 10k.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen any results for your specific CPU yet, but looking at a somewhat outdated [thread](https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/issues/25) (the algorithm and benchmark tool have had minor changes since), and the details on the project [README](https://github.com/tevador/RandomX#cpu-performance) for other Ryzen processors, I would guess at a minimum yours will achieve 5Kh/s.

It's really not possible to compare to what "high end GPUs" will achieve because the code is not yet finished for GPUs, so there are no benchmarks to compare. The developers have previously signaled at GPUs hashing at roughly the same rate as they do currently though.

Comment: 5Kh/s but what is that relative to certain gpu's ?

Comment: GPUs are expected to be roughly the same HR as they do currently. The GPU code is still being worked on.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this with the RandomX benchmark v1.0.4 (Win64) because I am thinking about picking up a Ryzen 3000 CPU.  I only spent about 10 mins with it but was shocked how bad the TR4 platform performed (all tests were with LargePages enabled):

Ryzen 7 1700 @3.9 (3200 DDR): 5030 h/s (8 threads)

Ryzen 7 1700 @3.9 (3200 DDR): 4000 h/s (10 threads)

Ryzen 5 2600 @3.7 (2133 DDR): 3175 h/s (6 threads)

Ryzen 5 2600 @3.7 (2133 DDR): 3225 h/s (8 threads)

Threadripper 1950x @3.8 (2133 DDR): 4825 h/s (16 threads)

Threadripper 1950x @3.8 (2133 DDR): 1550 h/s (32 threads)

Edit:
Was curious about RAM speed, so switched my 1700 to 2133 RAM and got 3837 h/s, so memory speed has a huge effect.

Comment: why is the performacne so bad compared to Ryzen?

Comment: What is your approximate block finding time with the mentioned CPU?